# dpkg error when installing linux

Tags: upgrade, apt, 13.04, kernel, dpkg

After running:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install linux
```

this error appears:

```
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux:
linux depends on linux-generic; however:
Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          No apport report written    because MaxReports is reached already
                                        Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic
linux-image-3.8.0-21-generic
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-21-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-generic
linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

os: ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Comment: How did your computer in this state?

Comment: This does not look like a valid command: sudo apt-get install linux . Why are you using that command? Try: sudo apt-get update . What happens?

Comment: my computer is work but cannot update.